# writing an api for python that can be installed using setup.py method

Tags: python, django, api, twitter, setup.py

I am new at writing APIs in python, in any language for that matter. I was hoping to get pointers on how i can create an API that can be installed using setup.py method and used in other python projects. Something similar to the twitterapi.

I have already created and coded all the methods i want to include in the API. I just need to know how to implement the installation so other can use my code to leverage ideas they may have. Or if i need to format the code a certain way to facilitate installation.

I learn best with examples or tutorials.

Thanks so much.

Comment: http://docs.python.org/distutils/ describes the Python Distribution Utilities (“Distutils”) from the module developer’s point of view, describing how to use the Distutils to make Python modules and extensions easily available to a wider audience with very little overhead for build/release/install mechanics.

Comment: @msw: make that an answer and I'd vote it up

Comment: same. I did find a useful tutorial here though 
http://mxm-mad-science.blogspot.com/2008/02/python-eggs-simple-introduction.html

Answer (score 1):

It's worth noting that this part of python is undergoing some changes right now. It's all a bit messy. The most current overview I know of is the Hitchhiker's Guide to Packaging: http://guide.python-distribute.org/

The current state of packaging section is important: http://guide.python-distribute.org/introduction.html#current-state-of-packaging

Answer (score 1):

The python packaging world is a mess (like poswald said). Here's a brief overview along with a bunch of pointers. Your basic problem (using setup.py etc.) is solved by reading the [distutils guide](http://docs.python.org/distutils) which msw has mentioned in his comment.

Now for the dirt. The basic infrastructure of the distribution modules which is in the Python standard library is distutils referred to above. It's limited in some ways and so a series of extensions was written on top of it called setuptools. Setuptools along with actually increasing the functionality provided a command line "installer" called "easy_install".

Setuptools maintenance was not too great and so it was forked and a more active branch called "distribute" was setup and it is the preferred alternative right now. In addition to this, a replacement for easy_install named pip was created which was more modular and useful.

Now there's a huge project going which attempts to fold in all changes from distribute and stuff into a unified library that will go into the stdlib. It's tentatively called "distutils2".